# first process of python popen pipe can't be killed

Tags: python, pipe, kill, popen, zombie-process

I am using this code

```
p1 = Popen(['rtmpdump'] + cmd_args.split(' '), stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(player_cmd.split(' '), stdin=p1.stdout, stderr=PIPE)
p2.wait()
# try to kill rtmpdump
# FIXME: why is this not working ?
try:
    p2.stdin.close()
    p1.stdout.close()
    p1.kill()
except AttributeError:
    # if we use python 2.5
    from signal import SIGTERM, SIGKILL
    from os import kill
    kill(p1.pid, SIGKILL)
```

when `p1` terminates then `p2` is terminated too.

The problem is:

If I manually close p2 (it's mplayer), rtmpdump/p1 is still running.
I tried various things like what is above but I still can't kill it.
i tried with adding `close_fds=True`.

so may be rtmpdump still tries to write to stdout. but why is this cause kill() to fail ?

full source code: http://github.com/solsticedhiver/arte-7.py

Comment: It simply does not kill the process. But no error or exception.


I was only using 'pgrep rtmp' to look after that process but in fact, it is in <defunct> state.


Looking for help on defunct process, I found that wait system call is needed for those process ??


By chance, I tried to add a p1.wait() and this works now. i.e. rtmpdump is really killed and <defunct>

    try:
        p1.kill()
        p1.wait()


wait before kill does not work. I don't understand how wait is supposed to work after kill but it is.

Comment: @solsTiCe: It would have been nice if you had answered your own question instead of editing it. Now others find your question again and again, when searching for old, unanswered, questions. Can you do so? And then mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix. call `wait()` after `kill()` to really kill the zombie process

```
# kill the zombie rtmpdump
try:
  p1.kill()
  p1.wait()
except AttributeError:
    # if we use python 2.5
    from signal import SIGKILL
    from os import kill, waitpid
    kill(p1.pid, SIGKILL)
    waitpid(p1.pid, 0)
```